# ASP.NET MVC: MsCharts working on dev but not on production

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, web-config, mschart

I'm having trouble getting MsCharts to work when deploying on my production environment.

The application is a .NET 4 ASP.NET MVC 2 site with IIS 7.5.

**Everything works fine when I'm running on Visual Studio's development server** however I get the following error when trying to run the page with the chart on the live site:

```
Error executing child request for handler 'System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil+ServerExecuteHttpHandlerWrapper'.

STACK TRACE:
at System.Web.HttpServerUtility.ExecuteInternal(IHttpHandler handler, TextWriter writer, Boolean preserveForm, Boolean setPreviousPage, VirtualPath path, VirtualPath filePath, String physPath, Exception error, String queryStringOverride)
at System.Web.HttpServerUtility.Execute(IHttpHandler handler, TextWriter writer, Boolean preserveForm, Boolean setPreviousPage)
at System.Web.HttpServerUtilityWrapper.Execute(IHttpHandler handler, TextWriter writer, Boolean preserveForm)
at System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage.RenderView(ViewContext viewContext)
at System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl.RenderViewAndRestoreContentType(ViewPage containerPage, ViewContext viewContext)
at System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass14.b__11()
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult)
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName)
at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore()
at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<>c__DisplayClass8.b__4()
at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass1.b__0()
at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)

BASE EXCEPTION:
No http handler was found for request type 'GET'

STACK TRACE:
at System.Web.HttpApplication.MapIntegratedHttpHandler(HttpContext context, String requestType, VirtualPath path, String pathTranslated, Boolean useAppConfig, Boolean convertNativeStaticFileModule)
at System.Web.HttpServerUtility.Execute(String path, TextWriter writer, Boolean preserveForm)
```

Having looked around the web a bunch I've struggled to find a definitive answer on how to get MVC MsCharts working in .NET 4 so I've picked up bits and pieces every-which where, to put in my web.config. I'm not sure if it's all needed or in the right place. The application's root web.config looks like this (after removing the superfluous stuff):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<configuration>

    <appSettings>
        <add key="ChartImageHandler" value="storage=file;URL=~/App_Data/MicrosoftChartControls/;timeout=20;" />
    </appSettings>

    <system.web>

        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
            <assemblies>
                <add assembly="System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
            </assemblies>
        </compilation>

        <httpHandlers>
            <add path="ChartImg.axd" verb="GET,HEAD,POST" type="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartHttpHandler, System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" validate="false"/>
        </httpHandlers>

    <system.web>
</configuration>
```

And my web.config in the root Views folder looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <pages>
            <controls>
                <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting" assembly="System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
            </controls>
        </pages>
    </system.web>

    <system.webServer>
        <handlers>
            <remove name="ChartImageHandler"/>
            <add name="ChartImageHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="GET,HEAD,POST" path="ChartImg.axd" type="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartHttpHandler, System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        </handlers>
    </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

In my Global.asax.cs I've done this:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    RouteTable.Routes.Ignore("{*pathInfo}", new { pathInfo = @"^.*(ChartImg.axd)$" });

    // ...
}
```

And my partial view that is rendering this chart looks like this, with `Model.Graph` being the `Chart` control:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<dynamic>" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"
    Namespace="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting" TagPrefix="asp" %>

<h3><%: Model.ReportName %></h3>

<% chartPanel.Controls.Add(Model.Graph); %>

<asp:Panel ID="chartPanel" runat="server"></asp:Panel>
```

The View that it's being rendered from is in an Area if that has any effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, found the problem. The following `<handlers>` section I had put in the web.config found in the Views folder:

```
<system.webServer>
    <handlers>
        <remove name="ChartImageHandler"/>
        <add name="ChartImageHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="GET,HEAD,POST" path="ChartImg.axd" type="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartHttpHandler, System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
    </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

Moving this to the web.config found in the root directory of the app made it work.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked within IIS to see if you have the required mappings configured for aspx pages?

Go into IIS manager --> Default Website --> handler Mapping

Comment: The rest of the site works.. would this be the case if it was incorrectly configured?